# Assign values from np array based on first column of array (NumPy, Python)

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

Given this array:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9,]])
```

I want to select a row of the array based on the first value, and assign the second and third values to variables. For example:

```
v = 4
if v in a[:, 0]:
    x = 5
    y = 6
```

In searching, the closest I've come is learning how to select an exact position of an array (e.g. `a[1, 1]` would give me `5`). I don't want to have to specify the exact position, I want it conditioned on `v`.

Also, I know I can get the position of `v` using `np.where`:

```
i, j = np.where(result_array == v)
```

Just not sure how to put it together to get the rest of the row assigned to variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! If the value `v` I want is at coordinates `i, j`, and I know my array is always 3 columns wide, I can get the rest of the column using:

```
v = 5
i, j = np.where(result_array == v)

x = result_array[i,j+1]  
y = result_array[i,j+2]
```

This will define `x = 5` and `y = 6` based on the value of `v`, located in the first column of the row.